# Illegal instruction [samba][nmbd][linux]

Tags: linux, debian, samba, raspberry-pi

Right after I did `apt-get upgrade` on my Pi Zero W running Raspbian Jessie, I ended up with a broken samba setup. Trying `apt-get install -f` i get:

Note: I added debian security repos, because i needed some packages that weren't in raspbian's ones.

> ```
>  dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure): subprocess
>  installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>  Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u4) ... Errors were
>  encountered while processing: samba E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg
>  returned an error code (1)
> ```

Now, could easily use ftp instead of samba, but i really need nmbd running to have netbios names working. If I try to `/usr/sbin/nmbd start` or `/usr/sbin/smbd start` i get

> Illegal instruction

and it's not really an handled exception, because I got this also by importing pycURL in python.

If you know any open alternative to nmbd, or if you know how to resolve this without reimaging the Pi please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried removing/purging the samba packages and then re-installing? - `I added Debian security repos, because i needed some packages that weren't in raspbian` - Mixing and matching repos from different releases isn't really a good idea.  It seems likely that you may be trying to do things in a way that simply cannot work.  But you haven't really given enough details to tell.  -- https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian

Comment: I tried to purge samba and all packages that i updated since i added debian repos, but no luck. I guess i'll build from sources what i need.